# File writing out of order in PHP

Tags: php, c, file, buffer, fwrite

Here's a super simple example of my problem. The code is expected to create 1000 files named file1 through file1000 respectively, and in each file, the numbers 1 through 1000000000 are supposed to appear in ascending order, one number per line as one looks through the file.

```
<?php 
for ($filenum=1;$filenum<=1000;$filenum++){
    $handle=fopen("file".$filenum,"w");
    for ($num=1;$num<=1000000000;$num++){
        fwrite($handle,$num."\n");
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

Upon execution, The first file file0001 is created correctly. The second file however contains numbers which are out of order. I believe this is because fwrite sends the string to write in a special buffer to be written later?

What I want is for the data to be written immediately. I don't care if it takes an extra ten minutes for the files to be written properly and I'm willing to use better functions in place of fopen() fwrite() and fclose(). I believe in C, there's a system function called OPEN that's used to create a file without any buffering and that's more of what I want.

Can anyone advise me as to the better functions I should use? or will I have to resort to creating my own function involving loops until the fwrite() function has written all data and praying the system wont lock?

Comment: i ran a test creating just 10 files, 10k lines, worked as expected.cant imagine a real world use for this :-)

Comment: I tried the loop method and some bytes are written but then after fwrite indefinitely returns a zero value, yet the file handle is valid.

Comment: You're probably looking for [`stream_set_write_buffer`](http://php.net/stream_set_write_buffer). Simpler file creating is possible per [`file_put_contents`](http://php.net/file_put_contents) or just [`touch`](http://php.net/touch) perhaps. Else investigate [`flock`](http://php.net/flock) if the cause is actually concurrent access or something.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want buffering, use `fflush` every time you use fwrite.
 http://php.net/manual/en/function.fflush.php

However `fwrite` function should work for your use case even though it buffers the data. The buffer is ordered.

I recommend you to **check the return value of the function**. It is always good practice to check it for IO-related functions. The `fwrite` function returns false if it didn't succeed. The document below explains other cases in detail. Example case is when your file system is full.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php

According to the comment in this page, `fwrite` also returns zero upon failures.